# What are the carried numbers called in an Addition problem

Tags: terminology, arithmetic, definition

What is the 1 that is carried called?

These are all Latin, would this make sense?

The Latin word for "carry" is "porto", would it be called Porto?

Just guessing here

Example:

```
  123  <-- Augend or Addend
 +  9  <-- Addend
______


   1   <-- What is this called?
  123
 +  9
______
    2


  123
 +  9
______
  132  <-- Sum
```

Comment: Carriend? I don't recall that having a name.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I like the thought process with that answer! Was thinking Addend maybe?

Comment: I have seen it called "the carry."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are referred to as carries in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Carry.html.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is what I'm looking for but will keep it open for a little longer +1

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_(arithmetic))

Answer (score 1):

In compsci, when we add binary numbers, we call this the "carry bit."