# what does "number of carries" mean?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

On this [lecture note](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-781-theory-of-numbers-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT18_781S12_lec3.pdf) on page no 4 Corollary 14 the term *number of carries* has been used. Can anyone explain what does it mean?

Comment: When you are adding together integers with the grade school pencil method it may happen that one you sum up, for example the digits in ones position, then there will be an overflow in the sense that the sum of those digits is $\ge10$. Then you will get a carry to then tens column and so on.

Comment: [What are the carried numbers called in an Addition problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/152699/318073)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of an addition problem:$$\begin {array}{r} 965257\\ +29568\\ \hline 994825\end {array}$$
There are carries in the ones, tens,  and thousands columns, for a total of three.  If I write the above in base $5$ I get $$\begin {array}{r} 221342012_5\\ +1421233_5\\ \hline 223313300_5\end {array}$$ and there are carries in the ones, fives, 625's,  and 3125's places for four.

Comment: so I do same ... except that I am doing it in base $p$?

Comment: Then you write the numbers and add in base $p$.  It works the same.  Any time the sum in a given column exceeds $p$, you deduct $p$ from the sum and carry $1$ to the next column over.

Answer (score 1):

If I add $14 + 25$, we get something that looks like

$$\begin{align}
&14\\
+&25\\
\hline 
&39
\end{align}$$

and we see that the ten's digit is the sum of the two ten's digits, and the one's digit is the sum of the two one's digits.

However, in adding $14 + 27$, we have

$$\begin{align}
&{\color{#F01C2C} 1}\\
&14\\
+&27\\
\hline 
&41
\end{align}$$

where I've indicated that we "carry" a $\color{#F01C2C}1$ after we add $4$ and $7$. That is what we mean by "carry": when the naive addition algorithm causes you to "carry" the effect of a lower digit to a higher digit.

Comment: so, the that particular corollary, i expand $k$ and $n-k$ in the base $p$ and add the number of carries?

Comment: Yep, you just do it in base $p$ instead